# namespaces in custom libraries best practices

Tags: c#

Just wondering what the pros and cons between the two following two examples:

```
using MyLib;

namespace System.IO
{
    public class IoService : IIoService
    {
    ...
```

and

```
using System.IO;
using MyLib;

namespace MyLib.IO
{
    public class IoService : IIoService
    {
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't add stuff to library namespaces that aren't yours.